# .htaccess redirect chain generated by multiple redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Wondering if you can help me?

I'm working on a site at the moment, and the following is in the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example/folder-name [R=301,L]
```

As I see it, this works in the following manner:

root domain rewrites using 301 to www. and then an additional 301 redirect to the /folder-name.

Ideally, I'd like to **remove** the middle redirect (i.e from root domain to www. and keep just the redirect from root domain to /folder-name.

*NB. there is a subdomain, let's call that products.example.co.uk - and access would be needed here.*

Is this possible? my .htaccess skills are not particularly tight so any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/folder-name/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, I'd like to **remove** the middle redirect (i.e from root domain to www. and keep just the redirect from root domain to /folder-name.

This should do it :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!folder).*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/folder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is there a way of excluding certain files from this? As an example I have a couple of urls that I would like to not be redirected to /folder that sit on the root domain?